# Match a single letter or a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be a simple question. 

I need to match if a variable contains either a letter or a digit. The following does not provide any result.

```
var onechar = 1;
if (onechar.match(/[0-9]/)) {
    alert ("A digit");
} else if (onechar.match(/[a-z]/)){
    alert ("A letter");
} else {
    alert ("Not a digit or a letter");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `onechar` is an integer, not a string. This really has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more efficient to use `test` for this sort of check, and it will automatically call `toString` on its argument

```
var onechar = 1;
if ( /\d/.test(onechar) ) {
    alert ("A digit");
} else if ( /[a-z]/.test(onechar) ) {
    alert ("A letter");
} else {
    alert ("Not a digit or a letter");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use toString() method to convert to string and use regex.

```
var onechar = 1;
onechar  = onechar.toString();
if (onechar.match(/[0-9]/)) {
 alert ("A digit");
} else if (onechar.match(/[a-z]/)){ 
  alert ("A letter"); 
} else {
  alert ("Not a digit or a letter"); 
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly, just try adding toString() function. So the code looks like:

```
var onechar = 1;
onechar = onechar.toString();
if (onechar.match(/[0-9]/)) {
    alert ("A digit");
} else if (onechar.match(/[a-z]/)){
    alert ("A letter");
} else {
    alert ("Not a digit or a letter");
}
```

Else than this, you could also use `\d` instead of `0-9`.
And since ignore case is not used, you should use `[a-zA-Z]` for matching a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Since no other answer addresses the condition "single" letter or digit...

```
var onechar = "1"; // 1 is an integer, it wouldn't have a "match" function
if (onechar.match(/^[0-9]$/)) { // add ^ and $ to mark the beginning and end of the string
    alert ("A digit");
} else if (onechar.match(/^[a-z]$/i)){ // add /i for case insensitive match
    alert ("A letter");
} else {
    alert ("Not a digit or a letter");
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the explanation. However, my next implementation is to accept onechar as input and this solution does not accommodate for this extension.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want to have:

```
var onechar = 1;
console.log( !!( '' + onechar ).match( /\d|\w/g ) );
>> true

var onechar = 'foo';
console.log( !!( '' + onechar ).match( /\d|\w/g ) );
>> true

var onechar = '+-)(';
console.log( !!( '' + onechar ).match( /\d|\w/g ) );
>> false
```

Comment: Matches `_`, which is a word character. And no need for `g` flag.